# laravel route api request working without any restriction for method

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I am a beginner in laravel framework, and while i am building a simple api routes i have faced a problem which is :
I have created in api.php

```
Route::resource('userss','User\UserController');
```

User controller has standard api methods (index,store, show etc..)
after that i listed the routes with this command :

```
php artisan list:route
```

and i have got the results as in the below image

[image]

route/api.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::resource('userss','User\UserController');
```

UserController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;

class UserController extends Controller
{

public $successStatus = 200;
public $appNameToken = 'stiskAppNameToken';
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //

    $users = User::all();
    return response()->json(['data'=> $users],200);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //


    $rules = [
    'name' => 'required|min:4',
    'username' => 'required|min:4|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:4|confirmed',
    'status' => 'required',
    'dept_id' => 'required'

    ];

    $this->validate($request,$rules);

    $data = $request->all();
    $data['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
    $data['verified'] = User::USER_VERIFIED;
    $data['verification_token'] = User::generateVerificationCode();

   $user = User::create($data);
   return response()->json(['data' => $user],201);
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return response()->json(['data'=>$user],200);

}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}

}
```

But the problem now is every time i make a request from postman to `mylocal.test/userss/`
with different methods (PUT,POST,GET etc..)
i got a list of the users ( index methods executed!)

what is the problem? 
why all methods requests are going to execute @index method body.

I already handled `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` in render function but no way

is suppose that  `Route::resource('userss','User\UserController');` handling such that problem?
and route my request to a correct method in my controller?

Update:
The problem i think was in postman or my local web server
Also after using Authentication you will not face this problem
thanks for you all

Comment: all `Route::resource` does is register those routes you are showing, that is all

Comment: Do you maybe have a wildcard route before this resource that catches all the requests and returns list of users? Sharing the `web.php` content might help more. And the controller code won't hurt to be shared :)

Comment: @Fadi Ramzi, Would you please to show your Controller as well?

Comment: kindly show you store function of UserController.

Comment: @lagbox yes i know, but i couldn't find the problem :(

Comment: @WeeHong
Certainly, i did

Comment: @fahim152 
i tried comment the code of store method to check but still the problem exits

Comment: What's your URL actually looks like when you're accessing via postman? [GET] `/api/userss` of course will use the index, but [GET] `/api/userss/1` will use your show method.

Comment: @FadiRamzi, i have try all your method. Everything works fine. And does not have the problem you mentioned.

Comment: @WeeHong
Yes all of the them work correctly, but if you try to make request as following :
method : put
url : mylocal.test/userss
it get all users, but in fact it should return method put not allowed exception
also if i change request to delete or another one i still get all users list

Answer (score 0):

It should have a `api/` in front of the URI if you are defining the route in `api.php` correctly.

Would you please double check?

```
+--------+-----------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                      | Name           | Action                                           | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                        |                | Closure                                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                 |                | Closure                                          | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/userss               | userss.index   | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@index   | api          |
|        | POST      | api/userss               | userss.store   | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@store   | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/userss/create        | userss.create  | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@create  | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/userss/{userss}      | userss.show    | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@show    | api          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/userss/{userss}      | userss.update  | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@update  | api          |
|        | DELETE    | api/userss/{userss}      | userss.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@destroy | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/userss/{userss}/edit | userss.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController@edit    | api          |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I cloned the controller you posted but everything is working fine.
Please refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have removed 'api' middlware from the route urls

Comment: The problem is if i try to make request with invalid method i should got 'method not allowed exception'
but i still got list of users when for example choose put method and url mylocal.test/userss

this request should be 'GET' and not put,post,delete etc...

Answer (score -1):

the problem is not from the `Route::resource()` because all it does is register them for the methods but to check anyways try registering the POST or any other method manually.
what i think the problem would be is the Controller so if you could share the code of the controller that you have it would be helpfull.

Comment: Hi Abdusalam
I have shared it :)

Answer (score -1):

when you execute GET request with postman to url mylocal.test/userss/ you gonna get all the users, because /userss is linked to controller function index, if you want to create user you should use /userss/create POST request, for update ussers/{user_id} PUT or PATCH method and so on. From the routes list you can see clearly method and route endpoint.

Best luck.

Comment: Hi My friend
My problem is not with ways to get,create,store,index etc....
my problem is when i make invalid request method like
method : delete,
URL: mylocal.test/users/
i should get 'delete method is not allowed' but what happen is i still get all users without any exception